# How to generate Recordio from Java object

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to serialize a list of java Objects (POJO) into RecordIO format. I have seen this BeanIO (http://beanio.org/) but it seems to be outdated. Is there any other Java library that could be used or a different way to do this ?

Once list of objects is serialized it will be used to train a model with SageMaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving my own problem. I decided to use Apache Avro instead of BeanIO. Spark allow to serialize using Avro (c.f. Spark-Avro). This seems to work however it did not fit my use case has I was trying to serialize an array of numbers.